# Pulling a single data element from an SQL Table Using C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I believe this is very simple, but I have spent a while Googling and looking at available API and I have not found a solution yet.

I simply need to get a data element (a double, in this case) from a known SQL table, when I know the Column and Row to get the data from, into my C# code.  For simplicity, let's say my table has 3 columns: ProductID, Price, and Weight.  I have access in my C# code to the ProductID, and I made a string which is the ProductID.  Now I simply need to get that ProductIDs corresponding Price into a double in my C# code.

I am brand new to SQL, but I believe a pseudoquery would be something like:

```
SELECT Price FROM tablename WHERE ProductID=id
```

Not too worried about the query (but I would appreciate help with that as well).  I just really need to know how to make a double in C# equal to that specific data element in the SQL table.  It should be dead simple, but I am making it harder than it is.  Here is some of the C# code so far:

```
SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Price FROM tablename WHERE ProductID=id");
double ItemPrice = sqlcommand.GetData;
```

Comment: I don't see "GetData" as a method in the SqlCommand class.

Comment: Yea, I should have specified, that is kind of pseudocode.  That's exactly the part that I don't know for sure what to use there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `ExexuteScalar` on the command object.

For example:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(connection);
cmd.CommandText = "select price from products where id = 123";
var price = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

MSDN Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

The word "scalar" comes from the mathematics world, and basically just means "a single quantified value".

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need.  The dataset returned by the query should be only 1 item, so it would just pull that 1.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. ExecuteScalar technically returns the first column of the first row, regardless of the size of the returned data.